# Mean of Multiple Columns in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, radix

I am trying take the mean of a list of columns in R and am running into a issue.  Let's say I have:

```
A B  C  D
1 2  3  4
5 6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

What I am trying to do is take the mean of columns c(A,C) and save it as a value say (E) as well as the mean of columns c(B,D) and have it save as a different value say F. Is that possible?

```
E   F
2   3
6   7
10  11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(E=(A+C)/2, F=(B+D)/2)
df

  A  B  C  D  E  F
1 1  2  3  4  2  3
2 5  6  7  8  6  7
3 9 10 11 12 10 11
```

Answer (score 2):

We can subset the dataset with columns 1 & 2, another one with 3 & 4, add them together, divide by 2, and change the column names with `setNames`

```
setNames((df1[1:2] + df1[3:4])/2, c("E", "F"))
#   E  F
#1  2  3
#2  6  7
#3 10 11
```

---

Or another option is `rowMeans` by keeping it in a `list` using the recycling logical vector, loop through the `list` (using `sapply`) and get the `rowMeans`

```
i1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
sapply(list(df1[i1], df1[!i1]), rowMeans)
```

---

Or another option is `unlist` the dataset, convert it to `array` and use `apply` to get the `mean`

```
apply(array(unlist(df1), c(3, 2, 2)), c(1,2), mean)
```

Comment: If I have a list of columns, say a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3 and wanted to take the mean score of columns a1,a2,a3 into a column and likewise with b and c to have a mean of a,b,c into a single column for each letter, could I do the same?

Comment: @DanteSmith In that case do `sapply(split.default(df1, sub("\\d+", "", colnames(df1))), rowMeans)`

Comment: Where does the \\d+ come into play? Is that splitting the column by number?

Comment: @DanteSmith  It is based on the column names you showed.  I see that you have numbers that follow a, b, c etc.  We are removing that with `sub` and splitting the dataset columns with prefix 'a', 'b', 'c'

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. So if the names of the columns were say, alow, amedium,ahigh and blow,bmedium, bhigh as opposed to numerics could you have it take the mean of every 3 columns to produce a= mean(alow,amedium,ahigh) ?

Comment: @DanteSmith  Sorry, didn't see your comment.  In that case, I would use `sapply(split.default(df1, substr(colnames(df1), 1, 1)), rowMeans)`

Comment: @DanteSmith BTW, what kind of patterns you have in the original dataset.  If we keep on changing the patterns, it will take a lot of time to solve

Comment: @akrun Hi, I am going to do something like this question but instead, I want to find the mean of every 10 columns of my data (which has 1000 columns and some NA data) how should I do it?Can you please guide me?Thanks :)

Comment: @akrunsure, thanks ... I thought maybe it is too basic ;)

Comment: @akrun I did, didn't I?!